Adjusting сontour plot settings for proper visualization of positive and negative values with custom levels
I am seeking assistance in creating a contour plot that displays both positive and negative contour values. I want the contour lines with positive values to be colored red, and those with negative values to be blue, as illustrated in the provided figure.

Furthermore, I have utilized the code provided by the author @azerbajdzan, which works well with their test data.
How to construct a contour plot so that positive contour lines are colored red and negative contour lines are colored blue However, I am encountering issues when applying it to my data, as it does not visualize the contour lines with negative values correctly, resulting in gaps. I am also unable to adjust the number of contour lines for positive and negative values. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to modify the code to suit my data and set different levels for the contour lines for positive and negative values.

mm = MinMax@data[[All, 6]]
d = 0.001;
cont = Table[{Rescale[k, {0, 1}, mm], 
    Blend[{Blue, White, Red}, k]}, {k, 0, 1, d/(mm[[2]] - mm[[1]])}];
ListContourPlot[data[[All, {4, 5, 6}]], ContourShading -> None, 
 Contours -> cont]


Data https://dropmefiles.com/oZrng

ContourPlot[Sin[ x y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},  Contours -> 5,  ContourStyle -> {Red, Red, Red, Green, Green, Green}]

You are using 4,5,6 parts of data, are parts 1,2,3 any relevant?

Columns 1,2,3 correspond to the original Cartesian coordinates X,Y,Z. Columns 4,5,6 correspond to the X,Y plane coordinates on the graph and the function value, respectively.

The resulting image strongly depends on the chosen contours values.
I think in the OP image some king of exponential distribution of contours were chosen.
data = ImageData[Import["https://i.sstatic.net/x8ARkRiI.png"], "Byte"] // Flatten // 
    FromCharacterCode // Uncompress;

cont = If[# < 0, {#, ColorData[97, 1]}, {#, ColorData[97, 4]}] & /@ 
     Join[#, -#] &@N[Table[E^n, {n, -7, 14}]];

ListContourPlot[data, ContourShading -> None, Contours -> cont, 
 PlotRange -> All]



With Table[E^n, {n, -7, 14, 1/2}].

data stored in image:


Your solution is great!!! I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.
